# Android Error: Default Activity not found

Tags: android, android-activity, android-studio

I have a launcher activity but android studio says "Default activity not found". This started after I added a login activity which I wanted it to be the launcher activity (meant for when the user signs up only). So I would like the Main activity to be the launcher activity once the user installs my app and provide their credentials. Your help is much appreciated.
This is my manifest with both my login and main activities.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="mypackage"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="22" />
    <library />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BATTERY_STATS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="mypackage.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="otherpackage.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/> 
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" /> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

    <permission
        android:name="mypackage.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <permission 
        android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"></permission>
    <permission 
        android:name="otherpackage.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"></permission>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/image"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="key"/>
        <Activity
            android:name=".Login"
            android:label="REGISTER"
            android:noHistory="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </Activity>
        <Activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAINACTIVITY" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </Activity>

        <Activity
            android:name=".MapActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAPACTIVITY" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </Activity>

        <!--<activity
            android:name=".MyMapActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MYMAPACTIVITY" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>-->
        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
        <!--Receives the actual messages. -->
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <!--this is to support pre KitKat -->
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="mypackage" />
                <category android:name="otherpackage" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name=".MapActivity$ResponseReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="mypackage.MapActivity.ResponseReceiver.ACTION_RESP" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service
            android:name=".MapActivity$MyGcmListenerService"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service
            android:name=".Login$MyInstanceIDListenerService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service android:name="mypackage.RegistrationIntentService"></service>

        <service
            android:name=".FetchAddressIntentService"
            android:exported="false"/>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

This is the main activity.

```
public class MainActivity extends MapActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MapActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        }, 8000);
    }
}
```

N.B The main activity extends my MapActivity, which extends FragmentActivity. It is starnge but I found this in logcat. I haven't implemented iheartradio library or anything. "Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.clearchannel.iheartradio.alarm.LiveDeltaUpdateService"

Comment: Can you post full manifest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change Activity to activity in manifest file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="mypackage"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="22" />
    <library />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BATTERY_STATS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="mypackage.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="otherpackage.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/> 
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" /> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

    <permission
        android:name="mypackage.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <permission 
        android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"></permission>
    <permission 
        android:name="otherpackage.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"></permission>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/image"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="key"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".Login"
            android:label="REGISTER"
            android:noHistory="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAINACTIVITY" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".MapActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAPACTIVITY" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!--<activity
            android:name=".MyMapActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MYMAPACTIVITY" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>-->
        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
        <!--Receives the actual messages. -->
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <!--this is to support pre KitKat -->
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="mypackage" />
                <category android:name="otherpackage" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name=".MapActivity$ResponseReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="mypackage.MapActivity.ResponseReceiver.ACTION_RESP" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service
            android:name=".MapActivity$MyGcmListenerService"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service
            android:name=".Login$MyInstanceIDListenerService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service android:name="mypackage.RegistrationIntentService"></service>

        <service
            android:name=".FetchAddressIntentService"
            android:exported="false"/>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo. `<activity>`, not `<Activity>`

Comment: thanks for catching that. Unfortunately, the error remains. I cleaned and rebuilt my project but no luck yet.

Answer (score 1):

A full AndroidManifest must contain the  tag and the  inside it.

You must declare the Activity with its fully qualified class name, and the package declaration can be ommited with a dot (.) if the Activity is inside the package of the application (declared at manifest.package attribute)

Such:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="br.com."
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="2.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="11" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_OWNER_DATA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_OWNER_DATA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

<supports-screens
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="false"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />

<application
    android:name=".BvApplication"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".BvNewsstandActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="br.com.digitalpages.reader.activity.HelpActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Transp" />
    <activity
        android:name="br.com.digitalpages.reader.ReaderActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
    <activity
        android:name="br.com.digitalpages.commons.activity.LoadingActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
    <activity
        android:name="br.com.digitalpages.commons.activity.WebActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
</application>
```

PS: You MUST read the stack trace generated from the error while running the application, you can use the logcat window at Eclipse or Android Studio or the Android Device Monitor included in the Android SDK installation.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

File->Invalidate Caches->Restart

Answer (score 0):

Simply deleting the .gradle folder in C://Users/username did it for me. Invalidating caches etc didn't.